# svelte - Animate tab drag and release with spring function

Tags: svelte

I have a tab at the bottom of my page which I want the user to be able to open by dragging and releasing it. How would I animate its position with Svelte? I've created two CSS classes for when the tab's open and closed like the following:

```
.tab-screen.closed{
    top: calc(100vh - var(--tab-height));
    transition: top 0.7s ease-out;
}

.tab-screen.open{
    top: var(--nav-bar-height);
    transition: top 0.7s ease-in;
}
```

Then when the tab is released above or below a certain threshold I set it to the corresponding class. That part of the animation works fine, but I want to set the position of the tab dynamically when it's held. What I've tried so far is using the [spring](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/spring) function and setting the style top attribute of the tab to the spring value as long as it's held. For example:

```
<div style={holding_tab ? "top: " + $mouseY.value + "px" : ""}>
```

The animation is really choppy and slow. I know this is not very neat way but I don't know how you're supposed to solve this with Svelte.

Comment: can you share a repl. I can help you to fix.

Comment: on:mousedown set `transition:initial` and at on:mouseup set `transition: top 0.7s ease-in`